# Adding a custom method to puppeteer.Page object

Tags: javascript, typescript, methods, puppeteer, extending

I would like to add custom methods to the `puppeteer.Page` object, so I could invoke them like so:

```
let page = await browser.newPage();
page.myNewCustomMethod();
```

Here is one out of many custom methods I have created. It finds first available element by the XPath expression, using the array of expressions:

```
const findAnyByXPath = async function (page: puppeteer.Page, expressions: string[]) {
    for (const exp of expressions) {
        const elements = await page.$x(exp);

        if (elements.length) {
            return elements[0];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have to invoke it like so...

```
let element = await findAnyByXPath(page, arrayOfExpressions);
```

To me, that looks weird in the editor, especially in a region where many custom methods are being invoked. It looks to me, a bit of "out of context". So I would rather invoke it like that:

```
page.findAnyByXPath(arrayOfExpressions);
```

I'm aware that there is a [`page.exposeFunction`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) method, but it is not what I'm looking for.

What is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Can you do this? Yes.**

You can extend any object in JavaScript by modifying its prototype. In order to add a function to a `Page` object, you can access the prototype of a `Page` object by using the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property.

Here is a simple example adding the function `customMethod` to all Page objects:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.__proto__.customMethod = async function () {
    // ...
    return 123;
}
console.log(await page.customMethod()); // 123

const anotherPage = await browser.newPage();
console.log(await anotherPage.customMethod()); // 123
```

Note, that you need a `Page` object first, to access the prototype as the constructor function (or class) is not itself exposed.

**Should you do this? No.**

You probably already noticed the red warnings on the linked MDN docs above. Read them carefully. In general, it is not recommended to change the prototype of objects you are using and haven't created yourself. Someone has created the prototype and he did not expect anyone to tinker around with it. For further information check out this stackoverflow question:

- ["Why is extending native objects a bad practice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/5627599)

**How to do it instead?**

Instead, you should just use your own functions. There is nothing wrong with having your own functions and call them with `page` as argument like this:

```js
// simple function
findAnyByXPath(page);

// your own "namespace" with more functionality
myLibrary.findAnyByXPath(page);
myLibrary.anotherCustomFunction(page);
```

Normally, you could also extend the class `Page`, but in this case the library is not exporting the `class` itself. Therefore, you can only create a wrapper class which executes the same functions inside but offers more functionality on top. But this would be a very sophisticated approach and is really worth the effort in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to JS world and learning everyday. Is there a better solution then? Like maybe extending the `Page` class by using own, custom class `MyPage` and have custom methods there?

Comment: @RA. You cannot extend `Page` as this is not exposed by the library. I added more information the answer. Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Thomas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57011946/9449426), if you want to override an original method of `Page`:

```
const extendPage = (page: Page) => {
  const { goto: originalGoto } = page;

  page.goto = function goto(url, options) {
    console.log("Goto:", url);
    // do your things
    return originalGoto.apply(page, arguments);
  };

  return page;
};
```

```
const page = extendPage(await browser.newPage());

await page.goto("https://google.com"); // Goto: https://www.google.com
```

To attach additional methods every time a new `Page` is created, you can listen to the `targetcreated` event from the `Browser` and extend the page in the callback:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

browser.on("targetcreated", async (target: Target) => {
  if (target.type() === "page") {
    const page = await target.page();
    extendPage(page);
  }
});

const page = await browser.newPage(); // extended page
```

If you want to add a new method and update Typescript definition:

```
import { Page, PageEmittedEvents } from "puppeteer";

async function htmlOnly(this: Page) {
  await this.setRequestInterception(true); // enable request interception

  this.on(PageEmittedEvents.Request, (req) => {
    if (req.resourceType() === 'document') return req.continue();
    return req.abort();
  });
}

declare module "puppeteer" {
  interface Page {
    htmlOnly: () => Promise<void>;
  }
}

export const extendPage = (page: Page) => {
  page.htmlOnly = htmlOnly;
  return page;
};
```

```
browser.on("targetcreated", async (target: Target) => {
  if (target.type() === "page") {
    const page = await target.page();
    extendPage(page);
  }
});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.htmlOnly();
```