# How to modify or add to default playwright methods (eg Page)?

Tags: playwright

I recently started using Playwright (coming from Cypress), and one thing I cant figure out is how to modify or add to Page methods.

In Cypress, I can make modify default behaviors of functions such as `cy.get(...)`. Or create new methods such as `cy.get(...).clearType(...)` which would differ from the regular type method in that it clears the input box before typing.

In Playwright (Typescript), I haven't figured out how to modify any behaviors or add new methods to the `Page` class.

I want to add new functions such as `this.page.clearType(...)` which differs from `this.page.type(...)` in that it clears the input box before typing.

Looking through the Playwright documentation, the only thing that I can see mentions modifying the test fixtures (which I dont think is the same thing?)

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: This is not possible. But you can wrap the Page class into your own class, see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-pom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check some `Puppeteer` module related answers of this kind of question.
YES, you can, but NO, you shouldn't do this practice as this is bad habit.
[Adding a custom method to puppeteer.Page object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980809/adding-a-custom-method-to-puppeteer-page-object)